# Apache Druid on MicroK8S

Tags: apache, kubernetes, druid, microk8s

How to deploy Apache Druid on MicroK8S on a Linux Ubuntu VM and to configure its available resources? Most of the repositories seem to be deprecated.

I have tried to use helm and looked for the YAML deployment file descriptions, though unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post guides you through a MiniKube setup of Apache Druid. Should be a similar approach:

[Clustered Apache Druid® on your Laptop – Easy!](https://imply.io/blog/apache-druid-for-preppers/)